# How to get the index no of line feed in Java?

Tags: java, substring

My text

```
Agency ABC Agency CHS
Location Mumbai
```

I want to fetch the value "ABC Agency CHS" from the above text. ABC Agency CHS is dynamic data and may change. Similarly Location field also may change.

I am using substring to fetch the values

```
data.substring(data.indexOf("Agency") + ("Agency").length(), data.indexOf("Agency") + 25);
```

Using above code, I am getting the desired values but I know this is not a correct solution.

Is there any option to get the index of line break for the Agency line ?

Someone please suggest a better approach ? Thanks

Comment: Why do you think this is not a correct solution?

Comment: @TheBlastOne because `Agency`, `6` and `25` are hardcoded, while he says that the data is dynamic.

Comment: Because if data change from ABC Agency CHS to XYZABC Agency CHS, then I believe it will not fetch the entire values. 

Similar case will happen if the value length is less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.substring(data.indexOf("Agency") + 6, data.indexOf("\n"));`

Edit: Since you have many line breaks you can use,

`data.substring(data.indexOf("Agency") + 6, data.indexOf("\n", data.indexOf("Agency")));`

This will get the string till the first line break after "Agency"

Comment: I tried earlier but it didn't work. Above data is just an example. I have to fetch the values from a file & there will be many line break in that file. I believe above code will use the index number of first line break in the file.

Is there any way of finding the line break of that specific text line ? Thanks for the response.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you so much. I have accepted your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use regular expressions. The first capturing group from

```
(?:^Agency )([A-Z]* .* [A-Z]*)
```

matches `ABC Agency CHS`, allowing for flexibility in the length of `ABC` and `CHS`. The leading `Agency` string is just ignored (but required for the match).

Comment: Also, I think the problem is too complex for solving it in a readable manner with substring-s and indexOf-s.

Comment: I think yours are slightly wrong. The .* will match to much, and you will end up with multiple lines. Shouldn't you do it greedy?Something like: (?:^Agency )([A-Z]*.*?[A-Z]*$) (I also added in a $ just to make sure you get a whole line, but it's probably unnecessary. )

Comment: I'm not sure about the `*?`, as they are just two quantifiers; the rest works for me. I tested with an online regex tester, and it seemed to fit the description, but you might be right in that it may not be strict enough. Thanks

Comment: * is greedy, so it will match the longest possible string. And since . matches linebreaks you will match multiple lines, as long as you have a line that ends with " [A-Z]*".The ? makes it match the shortest possible string (so the . will match as little as possible). But then I might have been right in that $ is needed, since you want the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

You might want this

```
agency = data.substring(data.indexOf("Agency"), data.indexOf("Location"));
location=data.substring(data.indexOf("Location"), data.length);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but as I mentioned above Location field will also be changing, hence can't use this code.